# error of change a year date format on MS Access 2012 by running a SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on Access 2012 on win 7. 
In a table, I need to change a year date format from '1-Jan-06' to 2006 and from '1-Jan-90' to 1990. I only need year.

This is my query

```
SELECT  *, 
CASE 
   WHEN CAST(right(year_date,2) , INT) <= 12 
   THEN 2000 + CAST(right(year_date,2) , INT) 
   ELSE 1900 + CAST(right(year_date,2) , INT) 
 END
FROM my_table;
```

I got error:

> syntax error (missing operator) in the query expression of 'CASE -- END'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does MS Access support "CASE WHEN" clause if connect with ODBC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920116/does-ms-access-support-case-when-clause-if-connect-with-odbc)

Answer (score 3):

Access SQL does not support `CASE WHEN` or `CAST`.

In Access, you can use  `IIf()` and `CInt()` to do what you intended with `CASE WHEN` and `CAST`.

```sql
SELECT 
    IIf(CInt(Right(year_date, 2)) <= 12, 2000, 1900)
        + CInt(Right(year_date, 2))
FROM my_table;
```