# Multiple output with one SQL query

Tags: sql, database, syntax

I'm trying to write an SQL query that will output multiple variables depending on how many times a specific quantity exists in the DB. This information will then be used in a chart.

The DB is set  as following:

```
ID | quantity | etc..
---------------------
1  |   2      |
2  |   6      |
3  |   1      |
4  |   2      |
.
.
.
```

Here is the query I made:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN quantity = 1) AS quantity1, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN quantity = 2) AS quantity2
FROM orders
```

But I want it to output like this:

```
quantity1 | quantity2
---------------------
    1     |   2      |
```

Instead I am getting these error messages:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: If you want to test your code on my database, the link is below...

-Link Removed-

Comment: You mean to do a `group by` on quantity probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another approach, maybe it helps:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN quantity = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS quantity_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN quantity = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS quantity_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN quantity = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS quantity_3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN quantity = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS quantity_4,
       SUM(CASE WHEN quantity = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS quantity_5,
       SUM(CASE WHEN quantity = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS quantity_6,
       SUM(CASE WHEN quantity > 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS quantity_more_than_6
  FROM orders
```

Here is a special query for MS Access:

```
SELECT SUM(SWITCH(quantity = 1, 1)) AS quantity_1,
       SUM(SWITCH(quantity = 2, 1)) AS quantity_2,
       SUM(SWITCH(quantity = 3, 1)) AS quantity_3,
       SUM(SWITCH(quantity = 4, 1)) AS quantity_4,
       SUM(SWITCH(quantity = 5, 1)) AS quantity_5,
       SUM(SWITCH(quantity = 6, 1)) AS quantity_6,
       SUM(SWITCH(quantity > 6, 1)) AS quantity_more_than_6
  FROM orders
```

Comment: I get the same error as in OP, but that looks like its on the right track. IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed.... what does this meeean??

Comment: I have added the database file to the OP

Comment: Looks like you use MS Access, it that right? I updated my answer for that case.

Comment: YES YES YES YES!!!! I didn't know there was a difference. Thank you so much! So for future reference what/how did you get to this?

Comment: I just googled for "ms access sql case syntax" and the first hit points to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920116/does-ms-access-support-case-when-clause-if-connect-with-odbc

Answer (score 0):

Use a GROUP BY clause , something like :

```
SELECT quantity, COUNT(*) AS num
FROM Orders
GROUP BY quantity
HAVING COUNT(*) > 6;
```

EDIT: You can add a HAVING clause

Comment: This is almost perfect! What I planned to do in my query was to find the quantities that = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and anything above 6. How can I achieve that?

Comment: This now **only** shows when the count is > 6. I need when the quantity is 1,2,3,4,5,6 **AND** when the quantity is > 6.

Comment: I have added the database file to the OP