# Access SQL: How to specify which record to return based on the "more important" condition?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have 2 tables (MS ACCESS):

Table "Orders"

```
OrderID  Product  Product_Group  Client   Client_Group    Revenue
1          Cars     Vehicles       Men       People        10 000
2          Houses   NC_Assets      Women     People        15 000
3          Houses   NC_Assets      Partnersh Companies     12 000
4          Cars     Vehicles       Corps     Companies      3 000
```

Table "Gouping"

```
Product  Product_Group  Client  Client_Group  Tax rate
Cars                            Companies     Taxable 30%
          Vehicles              Companies     Taxable 15%
Houses                  People                Taxable 13%
Houses    Women                               Taxable 15%
```

I want to join these tables to see which orders will fall into which taxable group. As you can see some products/clients are mapped differently than their groups -> if that is the case, the query should return only one record for this pair and exclude any pairing containing their groups. In pseudo-code:

```
If there's product-client grouping, return this record Else
      If there's product-client grouping ---//----- else
             If there's product group - client ----///-----else
                     If there's product group-client group ---///----
End if * 4
```

In that order.

Now my query (pseudo):

```
SELECT [Orders].*, [Grouping].* FROM [Orders] LEFT JOIN [Grouping] ON 
(([Orders].Product = [Grouping].Product OR [Orders].Product_Group = [Grouping].Product_Group) AND
 ([Orders].Client  = [Grouping].Client  OR [Orders].Client_Group  = [Grouping].Client_Group))
```

Returns both Cars-Companies and Vehicles-Companies. I'm out of ideas how to set it up to get only the most granular records from each combination. UNION? NOT EXISTS?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Use UNIONs. You could add an 'ImportanceRank' column or something to the unions, but just listing them in proper order with a SELECT TOP 1 should do the trick.

Comment: Malk, that sounds interesting - can you give me an example of how coul dI do thi (newb in sql)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to join these tables to see how many orders qualify as good,
>   mediocre etc.

Sounds like you want counts of the particular conditions...Assuming you have a SUM and CASE (I haven't written queries for MS Access in about 10 years...), here's some pseudo-code that should get you started:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN {mediocre-conditions} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MediocreCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN {good-conditions} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GoodCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN {great-conditions} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GreatCount

FROM [Orders] LEFT JOIN [Grouping] ON (([Orders].Product = [Grouping].Product OR [Orders].Product_Group = [Grouping].Product_Group) AND ([Orders].Client = [Grouping].Client OR [Orders].Client_Group = [Grouping].Client_Group))
```

[update] I don't like giving bad answers, so did a quick look...based on this link: [Does MS Access support "CASE WHEN" clause if connect with ODBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920116/does-ms-access-support-case-when-clause-if-connect-with-odbc), it appears you may be able to do:

```
SELECT SUM(IIF({mediocre-conditions},1,0)) AS MediocreCount,
       SUM(IIF({good-conditions},1,0)) AS GoodCount,
       SUM(IIF({great-conditions},1,0)) AS GreatCount
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin. I'm afraid my example was misleading - can you tell me If your comment is still valid for the edited question?

Comment: Best thing to do to figure it out is make an example output report based on the example rows you've already provided.  It is easier to say how to do a query if you see the data and see the expected output.