# Group ranges of values in access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, group-by

I have one table in access with like these:

```
Name:-----Birthdate:-----Section----etc...
John------10/10/1985-----etc...  
Mike------02/03/1976-----etc...
```

And many more.

How can I do a sql query that gets the age of the people in the table, counts it and shows ranges?

Something like:

```
Group1 ( From 18 to 25 ): 2 people  
Group2 ( From 26 to 35 ): 1 person  
...
```

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: How do you form the group? Are those static values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate someone's age using [`datediff`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php):

```
datediff('yyyy', Birthdate, now())
```

A [`switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14923507/50552) should allow you to group on ranges:

```
select  AgeGroup            
,       count(*)
from    (
        select  switch(
                  datediff('yyyy', Birthdate, now()) between 18 and 25, '18 to 25',
                  datediff('yyyy', Birthdate, now()) between 26 and 35,  '26 to 35',
                  true, 'other') as AgeGroup 
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueriesMustBeNamed
group by 
        AgeGroup
```

Comment: Great! More about switch function: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php

Answer (score 0):

It might helps you

```
    select d,cast(count(d) as nvarchar(max)) + ' persons' as total  from
(
    select case 
           when CONVERT(int,ROUND(DATEDIFF(hour,Birthdate,GETDATE())/8766.0,0)) between 10 and 20   then '10-20' 
           else '>20' end as d from  YourTable
) a
    group by d
```

Comment: Not sure if ms-access supports `case` (my version doesn't)