# CASE function doesn't work in Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm putting this SQL code in an MS Access query, but it doesn't work. "Syntax error (no operator) in the query expression." What's wrong with this SQL code?

```
SELECT URL_ID
CASE
WHEN URL_ID LIKE '*SEM*' THEN 'Google'
WHEN URL_ID LIKE '*DIR*' THEN 'Bezpośredni'
ELSE 'Others'
END
FROM URL;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does MS Access support "CASE WHEN" clause if connect with ODBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920116/does-ms-access-support-case-when-clause-if-connect-with-odbc)

Answer (score 0):

MS Access doesn't support `CASE` expression use `IIF()` OR `SWITCH()` instead :

```
SELECT URL_ID,
       IIF(URL_ID LIKE '*SEM*', 'Google', 
                  IIF(URL_ID LIKE '*DIR*', 'Bezpośredni', 'Others'
                     )                     
          ) 
FROM URL;
```

Comment: Why not `switch`?

Comment: Thanks! It works now! So MS Access doesn't support CASE expression?

Comment: @Yogesh Sharma, do     IFF or     SWITCH will work in mysql?

Comment: @matjan2. . . No, In `MySQL` you can use `IF()` or `CASE` expression instead.

Comment: @YogeshSharma could you recommend me some learing SQL materials and materials where difference between SQL in Access and MySQL are showed?