# Problem with SQL CASE sentence in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I'm developing a code for a project. I have an `.mdb` MS Access database connected to the project. I'm using the following code to show the information of a table in a GridView

```
conn.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Fecha, Descripción AS Mensaje, " + 
                                    "CASE WHEN Admin = true THEN 'Admin' ELSE 'Usuario' END" +
                                    "FROM Detalle WHERE IdParte = ? ORDER BY Fecha", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("IdParte", ddPartes.SelectedValue);

OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

GridView1.DataSource = dr;
GridView1.DataBind();

conn.Close();
```

Details of the error I get:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
>   HResult=0x80004005
>   Mensaje = Error de IErrorInfo.GetDescription con E_FAIL(0x80004005).
>   Origen = 
>   Seguimiento de la pila:

Comment: what is that error in english ?

Comment: Wanted to tag SQL alone, already changed it, Sorry

Comment: It says that you cant evaluate the exception stack trace

Comment: Are you sure that shouldn't be `Admin = 1`?  What is the column type of `Admin`?  Or maybe `Admin = -1` for Access?

Comment: I thought the same but I tried without a case sentence with `Admin = true` and it worked fine, so that cant be the problem

Comment: I'm not sure Access uses the same format for Case statements. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920116/does-ms-access-support-case-when-clause-if-connect-with-odbc

Comment: for access you need to use `switch` or `iif` in stead of `case`

Comment: Thanks @juharr, that did it. I used Switch and now it works.

Comment: Yes, @GuidoG. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a whitespace between the "END" and the "FROM". Just add it, and you should be OK:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Fecha, Descripción AS 
    Mensaje, " + 
    "CASE WHEN Admin = true THEN 'Admin' ELSE 'Usuario' END " +
    // Space added here -----------------------------------^
    "FROM Detalle WHERE IdParte = ? ORDER BY Fecha", conn);
```

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. But I already changed it and I keep getting the same error.